# How do I configure the up/down navigation in jquery/flexslider?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, flexslider

I have a WordPress site using Woocommerce and WooTheme's extension, Product Gallery Plugin. This plugin uses flexslider which is based off jquery.
Based on the code below, I added "mousewheel: true" at the end which turned on the use of the mouse wheel to navigate the product pictures. Problem is, whether I scroll up or down, it only cycles the images backwards. So if there's 3 images and image1 is displaying first, whether i scroll up or down, it'll jump to image3, then image2, then back to image1.
How can I configure this so it knows when im scrolling up(previous image) and scrolling down(next image)?

```
<script>
    jQuery(window).load(function() {
        jQuery('.product-gallery').flexslider({
            pauseOnHover: true,
            directionNav: false,
            <?php if ( get_option( 'woocommerce_product_gallery_slider_effect' ) == 'slide' ) {
                echo 'smoothHeight: true,';
            } ?>
            <?php if ( get_option( 'woocommerce_product_gallery_slider_navigation_style' ) == 'thumbnails' ) {
                echo 'controlNav: "thumbnails",';
            } ?>
            slideshow: <?php if ( get_option( 'woocommerce_product_gallery_slider_slideshow' ) == 'yes' ) { echo 'true'; } else { echo 'false'; } ?>,
            animation: "<?php echo get_option( 'woocommerce_product_gallery_slider_effect' ); ?>",
            direction: "<?php echo get_option( 'woocommerce_product_gallery_slider_direction' ); ?>",
            slideshowSpeed: "<?php echo floatval( get_option( 'woocommerce_product_gallery_slider_slideshowspeed' ) ) * 1000; ?>",
            animationSpeed: "<?php echo floatval( get_option( 'woocommerce_product_gallery_slider_animationspeed' ) ) * 1000; ?>",
            mousewheel: true
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.
Used the jQuery mousewheel plugin created here:
https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mousewheel

Just added the jquery min file.